# Matlab error error using - matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, matrix, compiler-errors, dimensions

I am trying to write a code for classification of data. I try to implement a sigmoid function and then I try to use that function in calculation the cost.I keep getting errors and I have a feeling that it is because of the sigmoid function.I would like the sigmoid function to return a vector.But it keeps returning a scalar.

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
%SIGMOID Compute sigmoid functoon
%   J = SIGMOID(z) computes the sigmoid of z.

% You need to return the following variables correctly 

g=zeros(size(z));
m=ones(size(z));
% ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
% Instructions: Compute the sigmoid of each value of z (z can be a matrix,
%               vector or scalar).


g=1/(m+exp(-z));
```

This is my cost function:

```
m = length(y); % number of training examples

% You need to return the following variables correctly 
grad=(1/m)*((X*(sigmoid(X*theta)-y)));//this is the derivative in gradient descent
J=(1/m)*(-(transpose(y)*log(sigmoid((X*theta))))-(transpose(1-y)*log(sigmoid((X*theta)))));//this is the cost function
```

the dimension of X are 100,4; of theta are 4,1;y is 100,1.

THank you.

Errors:

```
Program paused. Press enter to continue.

 sigmoid answer: 0.500000Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in costFunction (line 11)
grad=(1/m)*((X*(sigmoid(X*theta)-y)));

Error in ex2 (line 69)
[cost, grad] = costFunction(initial_theta, X, y);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace `g=1/(m+exp(-z));` with `g=1./(m+exp(-z));` in your method sigmoid

```
z = [2,3,4;5,6,7] ;
%SIGMOID Compute sigmoid functoon
%   J = SIGMOID(z) computes the sigmoid of z.

% You need to return the following variables correctly 

g=zeros(size(z));
m=ones(size(z));
% ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
% Instructions: Compute the sigmoid of each value of z (z can be a matrix,
%               vector or scalar).


g=1./(m+exp(-z));
```

Comment: It still gives me the same answer.

Comment: I tried above code and it worked for me. I tried scalar, vector and matrix and found no issue.

Comment: There was an issue in my cost function and sigmoid.So i cudnt see the difference in the changes you made.Thank you